# Spring MVC, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userForm' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I saw that a lot of people had my same issue, but even with the other suggestions, I still have this problem unsolved.

This is my web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

 <display-name>FINANCES</display-name>

   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param> 

  <listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener> 
 
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
   
</web-app>
```

This is my mcv-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
 >
 
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="danco.finances.webinterface.spring.config" />

</beans>
```

This is my jsp file

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/finances.css"/>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/faio/fontawesome-io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
 <div class="externalDiv">
  <div class="internalDiv">
   <div class="divUpperInfo">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>&nbsp;LOGIN
   </div>
   <div class="divUnderInfo">
    <div class="div-form" align="center">
     <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="login/login.htm">
      <div class="div-top-end-space">&nbsp;</div>
      <div>
       <form:label path="username" cssClass="form-label"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-1"></i> USERNAME:</form:label>
       <form:input path="username" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="div-separator"></div>
      <div>
       <input class="form-button" type="submit" value="LOGIN" />
      </div>
      <div class="div-top-end-space">&nbsp;</div>
     </form:form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Controller

```html
package danco.finances.webinterface.auth.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import danco.finances.webinterface.auth.model.LoginResult;
import danco.finances.webinterface.auth.model.UserForm;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

 @RequestMapping(value="/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView loginGet(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm, BindingResult result) {
  ModelAndView mv = new LoginResult("login");
  mv.addObject( "userForm", userForm );
  mv.addObject( "msg", userForm.getUsername() );
  return mv;
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView loginPost(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm, BindingResult result) {
  ModelAndView mv = new LoginResult("login");
  mv.addObject( "userForm", userForm );
  mv.addObject( "msg", userForm.getUsername() );
  return mv;
 }

}
```

What I don't understand is how spring can bind the modelAttribute, because every change I try I always receive back that message while I'm loading the JSP (and don't when I try to call the login).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can't inject the userForm when you call your jsp-page via get. The data is not available in springs model-data.

But when you submit your form spring puts the user-data in it's model-data and then can inject it to your post-call.

So you have to remove the parameters of your get-call.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginGet() {
    ModelAndView mv = new LoginResult("login");
    //mv.addObject( "userForm", userForm );
    //mv.addObject( "msg", userForm.getUsername() );
    return mv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but the problem is not into the login.jsp page. The code JSP that i posted it was for the index.jsp. In the end, index.jsp has the form, that should call the controller and returns the login.jsp page with the information of the username that the user inserted through the form.

Comment: please remove this entry (cause this is an "answer") and add it as a "comment" under my entry.